# Groovy script for set description on Jenkins Junit test results

Tags: jenkins, groovy, junit

I don't know how to set description on PASS or FAIL testcase using groovy script:
[image]
I am able to set description for "All tescase" or for Jenins builds using this groovy code but on test results not work for me:

```
def testResults = manager.build.getAction(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class).getResult()
def buildVersion = manager.envVars["BuildVersion"]
testResults.setDescription(buildVersion)

    testResults.getChildren().each { packageResult -> 
         packageResult.setDescription(buildVersion)
         packageResult.getChildren().each { testcase -> 
              testcase.setDescription(buildVersion)    

     }
    }
```

Can somebody help me with this please...?!
THks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
def testResults = manager.build.getAction(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class).getResult()
def failed = manager.build.getAction(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class).getFailedTests()
def passed = manager.build.getAction(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class).getPassedTests()
def buildVersion = manager.envVars["BuildVersion"]
testResults.setDescription("PASS")
testResults.getChildren().each { packageResult -> 
     packageResult.setDescription("PASS")
     packageResult.getChildren().each { testcase -> 
          testcase.setDescription("PASS")    
               failedTests = testResults.getFailedTests();   
                    failedTests.each { test ->
                test.setDescription("FAIL")
       }
    passedTests = testResults.getPassedTests();
       passedTests.each { test2 ->
                test2.setDescription("PASS")
       }
 }
}
```